# 12.10 Movie Player crashed entire system

Tags: video-player

Having intermittent issues using Movie Player to view video files.

Most of the time, I can watch the first video fine. But if I then close Movie Player, and open a second video file from Nautilus, my entire system freezes. It freezes so that I can't even ctl+alt+f1 to the terminal, and the graphics stay frozen on the screen, instead of dumping a kernel panic message. When this happens, I need to do a hard shutdown of the computer (hold the power button).

Rarely, but sometimes, I can watch many videos in succession.

The issue does not seem to correlate between the type of video file, or whether or not I am mixing and matching between types.

How can I fix this issue with Movie Player?

(note: for now, I switched to VLC)

Answer (score 0):

Use VLC forever. What's so special about that movie player that you don't even mention its name? There are thousands of movie players out there. Is it worth the troubles you're going through? maybe it's a buggy player.

[Here's what to do when Linux freezes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31818/what-to-do-when-a-linux-desktop-freezes).

Comment: It's called "Movie Player". It came with Ubuntu 12.10 (or at least I never specifically installed it). And it seriously hard freezes the system... none of the keyboard breaks work.

Comment: @parker.sikand just because it comes with ubuntu by default doesn't make it good, if you ever used any linux distro other than ubuntu, you'll realize that ubuntu has many shitty software installed, if you're happy with vlc stick with it, xbmc is a perfect option too.